# The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v14.20, v16.13 or v18.10

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, npm

I am getting this error although I am already have node js version 14.20.0, so can anyone please let me know what is the problem ?

```
PS C:\asu-mobile\moodleapp> ionic build
> npm.cmd run ionic:build:before

> moodlemobile@4.0.2 ionic:build:before C:\asu-mobile\moodleapp
> gulp

[15:41:18] Using gulpfile C:\asu-mobile\moodleapp\gulpfile.js
[15:41:18] Starting 'default'...
[15:41:18] Starting 'lang'...
[15:41:18] Starting 'env'...
[15:41:19] Finished 'env' after 744 ms
[15:41:20] Finished 'lang' after 1.32 s
[15:41:20] Finished 'default' after 1.32 s
> ng.cmd run app:build
Node.js version v14.15.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v14.20, v16.13 or v18.10.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
        
        ng.cmd run app:build exited with exit code 3.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
PS C:\asu-mobile\moodleapp> node --version
v14.20.0
```

Comment: did you find any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Do `npm install -g @angular/cli@11.2.2` and check again

Comment: yeah, do something like this to make the angular-cli version work with your current nodejs version, or just upgrade node from v14.15 to v14.20 or newer if you can

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have multiple node versions on your machine. Use a node package manager and make sure your on the proper one.

Answer (score 0):

It’s your Angular CLI version installed

The Angular, Angular CLI & Node have version compatibility matrix
https://angular.io/guide/versions

NOTE: Mostly, Your Angular CLI version (> 6.0.x) will corresponds to the version of Angular that will be installed through `$ ng new` command

For example if you have @angular/cli version 15.x.x, then your skeleton application angular version will have version similar to 15.x.x

---

Solution is,
Decide the angular version you want to work with. Then install coresponding node & angular cli

You can UNinstall the current angular cli installed
& then install a specific version of angular cli
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli?activeTab=versions

For example:

```
$ npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
$ npm install -g @angular/cli@x.x.x
```