# Node.js version v14.20.1 detected. The Angular CLI requires a minimum of v16.13

Tags: node.js, angular

I have been with this problem for about 2 weeks now.

I get the following error whenever I try running something with angular:

```
Node.js version v14.20.1 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum of v16.13.
```

I have removed nvm and node, installed Node manually, re-installed nvm, and installed multiple versions again but no matter what I do the Angular CLI doesn't want to get installed, the last thing I did was a suggestion made in this [The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v14.20, v16.13 or v18.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74761352/the-angular-cli-requires-a-minimum-node-js-version-of-either-v14-20-v16-13-or-v) but that didn't work either.

I have MacOs Ventura 13.6.

This is my .zshrc file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-1.8.jdk/Contents/Home

export MAVEN_HOME=/Users/benci/Library/apache-maven-3.8.8
export PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin

export ANT_HOME=/Users/benci/Library/apache-ant-1.9.16
export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin

export CATALINA_HOME=/Users/benci/Library/apache-tomcat-9.0.80
export PATH=$PATH:$CATALINA_HOME/bin


export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

this are all the node versions I have:

```
       v14.17.6
       v14.19.1
->     v14.20.1
       v14.21.3
        v16.0.0
       v16.13.2
         system
default -> 14.20 (-> v14.20.1)
```

hopefully, you can help me out, thank you in advance :)

Comment: `default -> 14.20 (-> v14.20.1)` How about you switch to `v16.13.2`?

Comment: have you used `nvm use 16`?

Comment: same thing, I get this error: 

Node.js version v16.13.2 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v14.20, v16.14 or v18.10.

Comment: nvm has a own "global" section for each of the installed versions. So it seems, when you switched versions, you also have a different version of angular cli installed (or did you reinstall angular cli after switching versions). So it would report different required node versions ... Nonetheless, the answer is always the same: To run angular CLI you have to install a version of node that is supported ... Try installing a recent version of node (ie the latest v18 or even v20) with nvm. Then switch to this version and reinstall angular CLI

Comment: @derpirscher. okokok I'll try that